# Hive populate table with subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql, hadoop, hive

I'm working on a Hadoop database, using Hive as the preferred interface. I want to be able to combine several SELECT statements into one query (kind of like UNION, but with each query populating a different column).The below query will return all the results I need in a single column, but I want to be able to use each query to populate an individual column. Any help on how to accomplish this would be fantastic - some sort of Hive equivalent to VALUES would probably do it. Cheers.

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE tstr_tmp SELECT * FROM
(SELECT time_stamp FROM http WHERE ext_hostname = 'exotichorse' AND dt = '01/07/2015' AND ext_url = 'http://lucy.info' ORDER BY time_stamp asc limit 1) as last_visit_of_day
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM (SELECT CAST(COUNT(hr) as string) FROM http WHERE ext_hostname = 'exotichorse' AND dt = '01/07/2015' AND ext_url = 'http://lucy.info' group by  ext_url) as n_hour_bins
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (SELECT time_stamp FROM http WHERE ext_hostname = 'exotichorse' AND dt = '01/07/2015' AND ext_url = 'http://lucy.info' ORDER BY time_stamp desc limit 1) as first_visit_of_day
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (SELECT ext_url FROM http  WHERE ext_url = 'http://lucy.info' group by ext_url) as domain_name
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (SELECT CAST(count(*) as string) FROM http WHERE ext_hostname = 'exotichorse' AND dt = '01/07/2015' AND ext_url = 'http://lucy.info' group by ext_url) as n_http_requests
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (SELECT int_ip FROM http WHERE ext_hostname = 'exotichorse' group by int_ip) as internal_ip;
```

As requested below, each query will return a single value as a string. For this particular query set, the following results will be returned;

```
00:08:00
2
07:00:00
http://lucy.info
2
192.168.0.22
```

I am working on a database that will tell me about user traffic, so this subset would populate the following table;

```
CREATE TABLE metric_http_domain_time_summary( last_visit_of_day string, n_hour_bins string, first_visit_of_day string, domain_name string, n_http_requests string, internal_ip string) PARTITIONED BY (dt string, hr string, origin string, cl string, st string);
```

I know that I need to partition the data going in, but I'm fairly confident on that part and will edit it in once I've managed to get the un-partitioned queries running. The gap in my ability is stringing subqueries together to populate a table.

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.  It is not clear what the data looks like . . . in particular, how many rows does each subquery return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going away and thinking about this for a good long while, I've worked out the answer. UNION was un-necessary and actually getting in the way. This query will return the above output as needed. Will leave this live in case someone else has the same problem. I have had to strip out the ext_url due to stack overflow reputation limitations, but the concept will work.

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT time_stamp FROM http WHERE referrer_hostname = 'exotichorse' AND dt = '01/07/2015' AND ext_url = 'ext_url_here' ORDER BY time_stamp asc limit 1) as last_visit_of_day,
(SELECT CAST(COUNT(hr) as string) FROM http WHERE referrer_hostname = 'exotichorse' AND dt = '01/07/2015' AND ext_url = 'ext_url_here' group by  ext_url) as n_hour_bins,
(SELECT time_stamp FROM http WHERE referrer_hostname = 'exotichorse' AND dt = '01/07/2015' AND ext_url = 'ext_url_here' ORDER BY time_stamp desc limit 1) as first_visit_of_day,
(SELECT ext_url FROM http  WHERE ext_url = 'http://lucy.info' group by ext_url) as domain_name,
(SELECT CAST(count(*) as string) FROM http WHERE referrer_hostname = 'exotichorse' AND dt = '01/07/2015' AND ext_url = 'ext_url_here' group by ext_url) as n_http_requests,
(SELECT int_ip FROM http WHERE referrer_hostname = 'exotichorse' group by int_ip) as internal_ip;
```